# How do I fix the problem with master page view (html)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, master-pages

I was given a html code for a master page for my website. The original page had a beautiful design, but when i copied it it showed a blank page with the text that was in the original site, but without anything like pictures or such. Im working with visual studio. Please help.

Comment: Start by creating provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which others can use to re-create the issue that you're facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the location of the pictures etc., is relative to their original folder. If you just copied HTML and CSS code, it looks for pictures related to its new origin. You need to move the folders with the pictures to the same folder.